# Get email clients in UIActionSheet

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, email

I want to get email clients into an Action and when I click on an email client the email should send from that particular client. Can anyone tell me how to implement it? 
[Please click on this for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3EqZ.jpg)

It should look like above image.

Comment: What do you exactly want?

Comment: In a UIActionSheet I want to display all email Clients so that I can send emails from selected email client

Comment: you meant to list installed email client apps and on clicking it, open the app to send your email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will helps you.

```
UIActionSheet* sheet = [[[UIActionSheet alloc] init] autorelease];
sheet.title = @"Add Accounts";
sheet.delegate = self;
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"iCloud"];
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Google"];
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Yahoo"];
if (condition)
[sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"XYZ"];
sheet.cancelButtonIndex = [sheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
```

then you have to create method for itemclick from actionsheet , you have to open mail app using following code

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    MFMailComposeViewController * emailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    emailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [emailController setSubject:subject];
    [emailController setMessageBody:mailBody isHTML:YES];   
    [emailController setToRecipients:recipients];

    [self presentViewController:emailController animated:YES completion:nil];

    [emailController release];
}
// Show error if no mail account is active
else {
    UIAlertView * alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"You must have a mail account in order to send an email" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK") otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Note, if you want to send the email from within your app itself, you can use the **MFMailComposeViewController**.

Comment: you have to add the email id to whom you want to send email in 'setToRecipients' in my code.

Comment: But the mails will go only from mail client(mail application) but I want to go from that particular client. Any third party class are there for this?

Comment: then, You need to use custom URL Scheme.

Comment: ex. for Gmail app, you have to use -  googlegmail://

Comment: Sorry to ask can you provide me with an example ..I am new to IOS

Comment: NSString *customURL = @"googlegmail://";

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
{
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
}
else
{
  //not installed, show popup for a user or an error
}

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer it is working.After implementing this I got an error "This app is not allowed to query for scheme googlegmail" so I did this in my plist schema and issue is resolved . now I need to get some email clients in to UIaction sheet then it will work as a same
http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Comment: right. you can set various scheme for different clients and you can get mail for every client you want.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doesnt provide an API to fetch the clients. You will have to design the ActionSheet icons on your own, and in the MFMailComposeViewController on tap of "From" field, you will have to auto populate the field with the suitable email ID.